# Unable to delete team project in Visual Studio Online

Tags: visual-studio, azure-devops

I am using VisualStudio.com to manage my team projects which use TFS source control. However, I am unable to delete any of my projects. The steps I have taken so far are:

Log in to my VSO account and click the cog icon to go into admin mode. Click into a projects "Project Security and team membership page". In the permissions sections, set everything, including Delete Team Project to be allow, I saved this.

Next I go into the overview tab and I bring up the context menu for my project. It has two options, "set team as project default" and "delete", both of which are disabled options.

Comment: Can you make sure you are a member of the group that has the right permissions. In the permissions section, there should be a tab called `Members`.

Answer (score 15):

Follow the steps below to delete a project:

1. Open your VSO account from web portal **without any project specified**. (https://YourAccount.visualstudio.com/)
2. Click cog icon to open the Collection Control Panel.
3. Click "Manage collection security and group membership" link.
4. Check and make sure you have enough permission to delete a project on "Security" page.
5. Go to "Overview" page and expand the context menu for the project you'd like to delete.
6. Click "Delete" to delete the project.

Comment: (btw, note the date of this comment). re step 1: i couldn't get to the link as you described -- hovering over the visual studio icon at the far left of the menu *looks* like it will take you to https://acct.visualstudio.com/, but it always goes to https://acct.visualstudio.com/_projects. but this is actually ok. clicking the cog icon at this point will take you where you need. (it goes to https://acct.visualstudio.com/_admin.) you can delete a project from there. [a stupid amt of time figuring out how to do this. some help in the interface is *really* needed for this.] cheers.